# VB.net to C# char Encoding (1251) conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net, char

I'm trying to write a file (myfile.txt) with C# encoding(1251), but the result is different from VB.net.
When i write it with VB.net i get different result and when i write it with C# i get different result, and the VB.net result is the correct one, can someone help me convert CHARS from C# like  VB.net does?

**Here is the VB.net code that im using:**

```
 Dim path As String = "C:\\file\\myfile.txt"
    Dim objWriter As New StreamWriter(path, False, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))
    objWriter.Write(Chr(32) & Chr(48) & "1,0001,1" & vbCrLf)
    objWriter.Write(Chr(34) & Chr(49) & "Cola" & Chr(10) & "2l" & Chr(9) & Chr(194) & "60.00" & "*" & "1.000" & vbCrLf)
    objWriter.Write(Chr(35) & Chr(53) & Chr(9) & "C" & "300" & vbCrLf)
    objWriter.Write(Chr(36) & Chr(53) & Chr(9) & vbCrLf)
    objWriter.Write(Chr(36) & Chr(56))
    objWriter.Flush()
    objWriter.Close()
```

**And this is the C# code that im using to encode it to 1251**

```
 string path = "C:\\file\\myfile.txt";
        StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(path, false, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
        objWriter.Write((char)32 + (char)48 + "1,0001,1" + "\r\n");
        objWriter.Write((char)34 + (char)49 + "Cola" + (char)10 + "2l" + (char)9 + (char)194 + "60.00" + "*" + "1.000"+"\r\n");
        objWriter.Write((char)35 + (char)53 + (char)9 + "C" + "300" + "\r\n");
        objWriter.Write((char)36 + (char)53 + (char)9 + "\r\n");
        objWriter.Write((char)36 + (char)56);
        objWriter.Flush();
        objWriter.Close();
```

Comment: Why are you using numeric values for characters?  Chr(32) is space, Chr(48) is 0, etc.  I am not sure about C#, but in VB Chr(9) is ControlChars.Tab.  BTW - Chr(194) will not 'round-trip', meaning that if  it is encoded with 1251 and then decoded with 1251 it is not the same character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last 'Write' call to:

```
objWriter.Write(((char)36).ToString() + ((char)56).ToString());
```

VB calls the correct 'Write' string overloaded method because the VB syntax obviously identifies the argument as a string.  The C# syntax as you have it will cause the int sum of two chars to be passed (to the 'Write' Int32 overload) - you have to use 'ToString' to pass the concatenation of the two characters.
(The other 'Write' calls don't have this issue because they involve unambiguous string concatenation).

Comment: EXACTLY , THANKS A LOT MAN that was the case

Comment: I didn't know C# behaved like javascript.  so changing that line to use the js trick would also work? `objWriter.Write((char)36 + (char)56 + "");`

Comment: I don't know JavaScript, but in C# chars are treated like ints unless you force the compiler to recognize them otherwise - this isn't as much a problem in VB since you have the '&' concatenation operator - in C# '+' could mean either addition or concatenation with chars, depending on the context.

Comment: @ps2goat: Yes - that would definitely work - and less verbose to boot!

Comment: That's a good point. I always emphasize that the `&` should be used when  expecting things to be treated as string concatenation.  Now you've given me a simple example of where this could easily go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Those are different. In line 2, your vb example is using `chr(34)`, but your c# example uses `(char)33)`.  I see the same issues throughout the code, not just in that one place.

**EDIT**: In case you didn't catch the issue, you cannot write different values to a stream and expect the same result.  The issue mentioned above should use `34` as the value in both apps.  If you are using `Chr(34)` in VB, use `(char)34` in C#, not `(char)33`.

**EDIT 2**: the last remaining issue is your `\r\n`.  It should be `\n\r`, or, better yet, use `(char)Environment.NewLine`

If you want them to output the same values, use the same values in your code and in the same order.  There is no difference in encodings between vb and C#.

Comment: But C# doenst recognize Chr(35) , it shows me this error "Error 1 The name 'Chr' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Chr is a VB specific keyword/method. you may need to use (char)33 instead in C#

Comment: I use (char)33 but it doesn't not encode the right way :( , i get different results

Comment: @albaneso, my point is you need to look at the numbers.  If you are using `Chr(35)` in VB, you need to use the same number in C#: `(char)35`.  Using different numbers between the two programs is what is causing different output.

Comment: @albaneso, you will need to find **all** mismatched characters being written to the stream.  the order of the numbers must match exactly between the two apps or a different result is guaranteed.

Comment: I edited the post, now they are the same character numbers
I did what u said, did replaced same Characters i still don't get the same Encoding... this stuff is going to blow my mind , i don't know what Im doing wrong here

Comment: @albaneso, see the second edit about the new line characters.

Comment: I tryed it here is the oputput that i get from c#:

`801,0001,1
83Cola
2l A60.00*1.000
97C300
98
92`

and here is the output that i get from VB:



` 01,0001,1
"1Cola
2l A60.00*1.000
#5 C300
$5 
$8`